# jQuery functions with AngularJS element

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am receiving an element on my directive like this:

```
function verticalResizer() {

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (element) {
                $(element).layout({ 
                // more code
```

The problem is that I can't pass this element to a jQuery function. Is there any workaround so I can still use the layout function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument for the link function is the scope. The DOM element is the second argument.

Comment: Thank you! Solved with `link: function (scope, element) {`

Comment: And... it's not just 'DOM element' but jQuery/jqLite element.